# Mysql trying to load uninstalled plugin

Tags: mysql, handlersocket

In the past I've used mysql 5.6 handlersocket plugin, however then upgraded mysql to 5.7 and the handlersocket plugin is gone because it is not supported anymore. There is no real problem, because i dont use it anymore either.

The strange thing is now error log has the following line on server restarts:

`[ERROR] Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/handlersocket.so' (errno: 2 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/handlersocket.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)`

It is true that this file does not exist, because i deleted it. But also information_schema.plugins table has no entry of handlersocket anymore. So, why does mysql still try to load this plugin ? Where does this information come from, event though the information schema doesnt have that anymore ?

Comment: How have you installed the library/plugin in the first place? And what steps have you done to uninstall it?

Comment: @Progman i installed it with INSTALL PLUGIN command as usual. However, i did not issue the UNINSTALL command because i forgot before upgrading. After upgrade, plugin entry was missing and i deleted the file as well. Obviously, i did sth i shouldnt have done, but i am aware of it. I just wonder where does mysql still keep some info about the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a record in `mysql.plugins` table. Deleting it removed the warning.